# Why does github repo show working directory?

Tags: git, github

Since github repo hosted remote git repo, it's a bare repo without working directory.

But when we browse the repo on github web page, it only shows the files existing in working directory but not as bare repo showing `.git` folder.

So why is it different when we view the bare repo on github web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every interface to git repositories (including any web interface, including github) shows files from git object database, not from any working directory.

The object database contains commits, trees (directories) and blobs (files).